# laptop mutes after connecting to speakers or microphone

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones, speakers

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS currently. After installing updates I started facing a problem. My system mutes after I plug in my speakers or microphone and unmutes after I unplug it. I cant use the keyboard unmute button to unmute it after my speakers/microphone is connected. The mute/unmute button becomes fine after the speakers/microphone is unplugged.

How do I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening sound config on the speaker icon next to the computer clock. Every time you plug an audio device you need to check wich way is outcoming the sound.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The sound icon tells me that the system sound is on. But the sound button on the keyboard is red while the speakers are connected and there is no output sound.  The output tab in sound settings also say that the output volume is 100%. But no output sound.

Comment: @Dheeraj I think they mean, go to settings and change the device to the one you need.